# Azure CosmosDB: enable dot notation for MongoDB API

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

We are migrating our storage backend to Azure CosmosDB with MongoDB API. There we noticed that queries for array values using dot notation don't return any results.

As described in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/3d156465-8f12-4920-baf3-96dd1f5c8e91/query-array-value-with-mongodb-client?forum=azurecosmosdb dot notation is disabled by default.

Is there a way to enable it using the Azure Portal or CLI client?

Comment: Maybe using Azure Germany as environment is an issue here. I contacted support.

Answer (score 1):

The "dot-notation" on arrays should be enabled by default for all accounts created after August 2017.

Comment: @ozan, was Mike's answer the one that you were asking for ?